How can I call a 3rd-party Drush command from a custom Drush command?
Now that Drush Commands are no longer services declared in a drush.services.yml file, how can one module's Drush commands be dependency injected into another command?
For example, I was previously injecting search_api.commands into another command. But the drush.services.yml file was removed from the Search API module, resulting in an error.
Code:
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
      $container->get('search_api.commands'),
    );
  }

This worked until updating Drush to 12. Now, the given file cannot be loaded when running drush commands, as seen by the following error:

[debug] Could not instantiate
Drupal\example\Drush\Commands\ExampleCommands: You have requested a
non-existent service "search_api.commands". [10.86 sec, 15.44 MB]

So I need to either find a new method to inject the Search API Drush commands into my Drush command class, or I need to know how to call another module's Drush commands from within my own Drush command.

Dependency injection is now handled through Autowiring. it should be quite straightforward to convert your command class to use it, for example:
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drush\Commands\AutowireTrait;
use Drush\Commands\DrushCommands;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\Autowire;

class FooCommands extends DrushCommands {

  use AutowireTrait;

  public function __construct(
    // Service that doesn't need help to be located.
    protected EntityTypeManagerInterface $entityTypeManager,
    // Service that needs help to be located.
    #[Autowire(service: 'foo.bar')]
    protected FooBarInterface $fooBar,
  ) {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  // Code for commands...

}

Remember to move your command into a MODULE/src/Drush/Commands folder too, that was another change from 11.x -> 12.x.
To address the edits:
The command classes are no longer registered as services, so unless you register them yourself (in your module's .services.yml, for example), they can't be injected.
The alternative is to just instantiate them yourself
public function __construct(...) {
  // For a command class using AutowireTrait or with a static create() method.
  $this->searchApiDrushCommands = SearchApiDrushCommands::create(Drush::getContainer());
  // For command classes without static create().
  $this->fooBar = new FooBar();
}

Drush uses the same approach internally in Drush\Runtime\ServiceManager::instantiateServices().

What is the service name for Drush service though? For example, MigrateToolsDrushCommands

What makes you think it’s changed from your existing code? Whatever you were already using for the service ID should still be valid, but if not you’ll need to ask a new question with the updated details (code, error messages, etc.). The other approach, of course, would be to just look at MigrateToolsDrushCommands and extract the code you need from its command methods, I.e. inject the services it injects and use them directly, rather than executing the command wrapper itself

Drush error output told me it's failing. I've updated the original question.

That's useful to know, and that's what I was alluding to in the last bit of the last comment - rather than try to inject the drush command (which may not even be registered as a service any more), it would probably be better to mimic what SearchApiDrushCommands does in its constructor, which is create a CommandHelper, and use that to dispatch your commands. All of the drush commands in the search API class use that same helper class. You've probably heard the phrase "program to the interface, not the implementation", it's a (sort of, liberally speaking) version of that

I get what you're saying, but actually I have multiple command services being injected into my original class, so I'd much prefer to figure out a way to call 3rd party Drush commands rather than mimic them, as the code will require much more effort to maintain. Thank you for your help.

I checked, the command classes aren't registered as services any more, so they can't be injected. This is in fact probably why the services.yml was deprecated in the first place, because command groups don't really need to be registered as services. There's always old school PHP, like $this->searchApiDrushCommands = SearchApiDrushCommands::create(Drush::getContainer()); in the constructor. Or for services that don't use AutowireTrait/static function create(), new ServiceName();. This is how Drush does it internally too (Drush\Runtime\ServiceManager::instantiateServices())
